# Nginx - SSL Website shows up on desktop but not mobile

Tags: tls, openssl, nginx, ubuntu

So I bought a Comodo SSL from Namecheap and put my site up on a Ubuntu droplet on DigitalOcean on a `nginx` server.

My `default` virtual host file on `/etc/nginx/sites-available/`:

```
server {
       listen         80;
       server_name    www.navarra-rpg.com;
       return         301 https://www.----------.com$request_uri;
}

server {

    listen 443 ssl;

    root /var/www/--------.com/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/---------.key;

    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;

    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS;

    server_name www.navarra-rpg.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Here are the four files I recieved:

- AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
- COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt
- COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt
- navarra-rpg_com.crt

Of course, I then used the command to bundle them all up nicely to get the bundled certificate plus the key when I used the `openssl req` command.

Now, when I go to DigiCert's site to test and I type in my address... it says that I installed it correctly.

I checked out my cert installation to make sure I got the chain right:

- Comodo RSA Certification Authority

  - Comodo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA

    - ----------.com

I used the following command from [this guide](https://gist.github.com/bradmontgomery/6487319) to get the ssl bundle cert.:

`cat ---------_com.crt COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt > ssl-bundle.crt`

Why isn't my website showing up securely on my Android mobile but is on my desktop?

I get `NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` error on my phone along with upon pressing the `NET:ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` error

Comment: which android verison? Also you should look to remove SSLv3 support this is widely considered insecure.

Comment: @Oneiroi Will be sure to do that. Which android? Latest version. I Am on Samsung Galaxy S6... >_<

Comment: Ok we can assume Android 5.x in this case; and if you go to https://navarra-rpg.com via youy Android what do you see in the browser? any indicators as to the error would be helpful (screenshot would be ideal)

Comment: @Oneiroi I added in my mobile error on the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find some more information by "tapping" `NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` on the first page see this example here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o8iJE7p-W4M

In short `NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` indicates the certificate authority is not trusted by your Android device.

Try opening a support case with the CA (Comodo), a quick google seems this is not an uncommon issue for comodo certs.

Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340298/certificate-trusted-on-pc-but-not-in-android

Also for secure SSL nginx configuration refer to: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS

Comment: It worked. :) I got a cert from Comodo and it was all good.

Comment: +1 for security link that also helps with performance.